# Setting a property to null

Tags: javascript

Having the code:

```
foo = {};
foo.bar = 78;
foo.bar.baz = null;
```

testing `foo.bar.baz` against `null`:

```
if( foo.bar.baz === null )
  console.log("foo.bar.baz is null");
else
  console.log("foo.bar.baz is NOT null");
```

results in "foo.bar.baz is NOT null". Why isn't it `null` since i set it up explicitly?

Comment: `foo.bar` can not be a number and a object at the same time

Comment: @tkausl is right, and number object doesn't have baz property, so you can't really update this property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because primitives don't have properties, and the value in `foo.bar` is a primitive.

When you access (get or set) a property on a primitive, the JavaScript engine creates an object for that primitive, sets or retrieves the property value (if any), and then throws away the object. (That's why `(42).toString()` works; the primitive is promoted to an object backed by `Number.prototype`, `toString` is retrieved from that object and called with `this` referring to the object, and then the object is thrown away.)

So although an object was created in your `foo.bar.baz = null` statement, and its `baz` property was set to `null`, that object was never stored anywhere (certainly not in `foo.bar`), and so it got thrown away. Later when you do `if (foo.bar.baz === null)`, a *new* object, which doesn't have the property, is created and you get `undefined` for its `baz` property (because it doesn't have one). (Naturally, JavaScript engines can optimize this process to avoid unnecessary object creation.)

We could create a function on `Number.prototype` that returned the object that gets created, to demonstrate that the object creation really does happen each time you access a property on a primitive:

```js
// Add a `nifty` method to numbers
Object.defineProperty(
  Number.prototype,
  "nifty",
  {
    value: function() {
      console.log("Number#nifty called");
      return this;
    }
  }
);

var n = 42;                 // A primitive number
console.log(typeof n);      // "number"
var obj1 = n.nifty();       // Creates an object, which we keep
console.log(typeof obj1);   // "object"
var obj2 = n.nifty();       // Do it again, and a new object is created
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // false, they're not the same object
```

If you want to set properties on a number and keep them, you can do that by explicitly creating a `Number` object:

```js
var n = new Number(42);
n.baz = null;
console.log(n.baz === null); // true
```

It's rare to want to do that, but it's possible. Just beware that as we showed earlier, two `Number` **objects** with the same raw value are not `==` to each other:

```js
var n1 = new Number(42);
var n2 = new Number(42);
console.log(n1 == n2);  // false
console.log(n1 === n2); // false
```

`>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` will coerce the number back to a primitive and use the raw value, but `==` and `===` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Working with numeric value as object in strict mode will run into exception.

By default `foo.bar.baz = null` will be undefined because `foo.bar` is not object and `.baz` will not be set.

This is Your code in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';

var foo = {};
foo.bar = 78;
foo.bar.baz = null;

if(foo.bar.baz === null )
  alert("foo.bar.baz is null");
else
  alert("foo.bar.baz is NOT null");
```

here is solution:

```js
'use strict';

var foo = {};
foo.bar = {};
foo.bar.num = 78; // your number here
foo.bar.baz = null;

if( foo.bar.baz === null )
  alert("foo.bar.baz is null");
else
  alert("foo.bar.baz is NOT null");
```

p.s. always put `'use strict'` inside Your JS files to be able to make JS less versatile.

Comment: Now *that's* a feature of strict mode I was not aware of. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.bar` is a number primitive, not an object. You can't set properties on a number primitive, but you can set properties on a number object.

```
foo = {};
foo.bar = new Number(78);
foo.bar.baz = null;
```

Now `foo.bar.baz == null`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
foo = {};
foo.bar = 78;
foo.bar.baz = null;

console.log(foo.bar.baz); // undefined
```

since you are trying to set a property of a number.